# passport js to authenticate user login not working Local Strategy not being called

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, ejs

Can someone explain to me the reason why LocalStrategy is not being called when I'm trying to login?
Basically nothing happens when I login it just refreshes the page.

```
require("dotenv").config()
const ejs = require("ejs");
const express = require("express")
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const passport = require("passport")
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const flash = require("express-flash")
//const User = require("./users")
//creating application
const app = express()
//const initializePassport = require("./passportconfig")


//connection to MongoDB with mongoose
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main() { await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/passportDB') }

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    userEmail: String
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

//middleware
//connecting to ejs
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
//connecting error text giver
app.use(flash())
//setup session
app.use(session({
    secret: String(process.env.SECRET),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 }
}))

//connecting to body-parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


//passport.js
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

//serialize and deserialize session
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log('Deserialize user called.');
    // @ts-ignore
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log('Deserialize user called.');
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

//initializePassport(passport)
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ userEmail: email }, async function (err, user) {
        if (err) {return done(err)}
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' }) }
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password) == false) { return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' }) }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}))

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect("/login");
}

app.get("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs', { name: "Kyle" })
})

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render('register.ejs')
})

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    //10 is the value to generate the salt higher = more salted
    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        const user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            password: hashedPassword,
            email: req.body.email
        })
        await user.save()
        console.log(user)
        res.redirect('login')
    } catch {
        res.redirect('register')
    }
})

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
})
```

Is there something I am missing?
The app.post for register is working all the data is entering the database it's simply for the login that's not working and it's because passport.authenticate is not working for the login post